# Is it possible to specify a default value for a parameter to a lambda expression in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

Is the following correct Python code? If not, what's the correct syntax for this kind of expression?

```
x = lambda (y, z=None) : y if z == None else z
```

Comment: As a side note, if you are storing your lambda function anyway, you might as well use `def`.

Comment: Have you tried running it? What was the result -- did it behave like you expected it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses:

```
x = lambda y, z=None: y if z is None else z
```